# How to use python to control the mouse playing games on "msi app player"

Tags: python, android-emulator, mouse, pyautogui

I'm using Python to control the mouse to do some autoclicking on an Android Emulator.I am using pyautogui and PyDirectInput to control the mouse; however after the mouse moves onto the emulator the click() function runs but does not work and no clicking occurs, no error either.

Here are the clicking functions and the main loop:

```py
import pyautogui as pi
import time
import pydirectinput as pyd


def click_shit(x, y):
    pyd.moveTo(x,y)
    for i in range(0,200,1):
        pyd.click()
        time.sleep(0.04)
  
def click_reload(x,y,x2,y2):
    pyd.moveTo(x,y)
    pyd.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyd.moveTo(x2,y2)
    pyd.click()  
while 1 :
     click_shit(x, y)
     time.sleep(3)
     click_reload(x,y,x2,y2)
     time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Could you show what you've tried? (What code have you written?)

Comment: Could while block be inside `click_reload()` function?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The while loop in my  code is intended to continuously execute the two functions for repeated clicking actions. Placing the while loop inside the click_reload function might not suit my needs, as it would result in the click_shit function being executed only once while the click_reload function would enter an infinite loop. My primary issue is with the auto-click functionality not working on the MSI App Player emulator. I appreciate your suggestion and will consider other potential solutions to address the issue of the clicks not working

Comment: @toyotaSupra, if the `while` loop was inside the function then the code would be recursive.  it is not clear what the OP wants to achieve, but i doubt it is that.

Answer (score 1):

I read through your code a few times, and tested it myself, and I don't think that it is a problem with the written code. Most likely what is going on is that `pydirectinput` cannot access the Android Emulator, and this can be caused by multiple things. In my experience, the best way to move on is to use a different module. You mentioned using `pyautogui`, although you didn't post the code when using the module (it would help if you posted it to see if the problem lies there).

As written in your code, in the `click_****(x, y)` function, you have `pyd.moveTo(x, y)`, which moves the mouse to the desired coordinates x and y. You have to move the mouse to the location before you click, which is not desirable. `Pyautogui` has the `click()` function, which allows you to click (x, y) coordinates *without* moving the mouse there first. Of course, if you truly wanted the mouse moving, you could use pyautogui's `moveTo()` or `move()` functions, which allows you to either move the mouse to specific coordinates, or move the mouse a certain number of pixels, depending on where the mouse is located and the relative position to the screen.

Combining all this into code, here's a possible solution:

```
import pyautogui as pi
import time


def click_****(x, y):
    for i in range(0,200,1):
        pi.click(x, y) #clicks at (x, y) coordinates
        time.sleep(0.04)

def click_reload(x,y,x2,y2):
    pi.click(x, y) #clicks at (x, y) coordinates
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pi.click(x2, y2) #clicks at (x2, y2) coordinates
while 1:
    click_****(x, y)
    time.sleep(3)
    click_reload(x,y,x2,y2)
    time.sleep(1)
```

and this might work for you. However, I don't know if `pyautogui` will be able to access the platform you are using, so I decided to include another module for an example. `Pynput` allows control and detection of both the mouse and keyboard.

Here's a code snippet for an example:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time

mouse = Controller()

def click_****(x, y):
    mouse.position = (x, y) #sets mouse position to (x, y) coordinates
    for i in range(0,200,1):
        mouse.click(left, 1) #clicks once at current position
        time.sleep(0.04)

def click_reload(x,y,x2,y2):
    mouse.position = (x, y) #sets mouse position to (x, y) coordinates
    mouse.click(left, 1) #clicks once at current position
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mouse.position = (x2, y2) #sets mouse position to (x2, y2)
    mouse.click(left, 1) #clicks once at current position
while 1:
    click_****(x, y)
    time.sleep(3)
    click_reload(x,y,x2,y2)
    time.sleep(1)
```

and that should work for you. Of course, I know there can be problems with that as well, so I know there is another python module called `mouse`, which can be used to control the mouse, but I am not familiar with it. If you want to learn more about it, or any other things I suggested in this answer, you should see the links I have below.

Pyautogui: https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI

Pynput: https://pypi.org/project/pynput

Mouse: https://pypi.org/project/mouse